# can I use numpy array format of image, as a input for yolov5?

Tags: python, numpy, yolov5

I am using yolov5 model from https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/
it has two method for inference: using torch.hub and then model(img)
or
git clone and then using detect --source img

in first method we can give it img as numpy array, but I want using numpy array as a input for second method.
pls dont say use cv2.imwrite and then pass img to detect. I want do this without saving image. thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.